# How to synchronize GraphQL changes from Appsync to Android using amplify?

Tags: android, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I migrated a flutter native plugin for appsync to amplify.
Now I wonder how to generate code in the android part of my flutter project after updating the GraphQL in the appsync console.

Initially i used:

`amplify init
amplify add api
amplify add codegen --apiId <MY-API-ID>`

this worked like a charm. 
However when I want to generate updated code using

`amplify api update`
I get the reply

`The selected resource is not managed using AWS Cloudformation. Please use the AWS AppSync Console to make updates to your API - de.sistar.fcsp_rad`

So I guess I did not understand the whole workflow. How do I update my android client project after updating the GraphQL in the AWS Appsync Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `amplify codegen statements` to regenerate the queries and such, then kick off a Gradle build again.

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/codegen#amplify-codegen-statements-

Comment: Running `amplify codgen` or `amplify codgen statements` resulted in display of the cli splash/help screen. So I assumed that this command was not correct/ not understood by the cli.
After running `amplify configure codegen` I could run `amplify codegen statements`